# sencha touch scrollable doesn't work with chrome firebug

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch, firebug, scrollable

http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.1/docs/Ext.scroll.Scroller.1/viewer.html

That example works fine in chrome, until firebug is off, but when I press F12 to get firebug in chrome, this example stops working and there is no scroll anymore.

Any way to get scrollable working with Firebug ?

Comment: Hey Riz, I think you will have better luck getting this answered if you ask a question. It's quite a leap to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open firebug in chrome, click on setting icon on right bottom corner, choose overrides from left side, then toggle option "Emulate touch events", when it is ON, scrolling does not work. Better turn it off if scrolling is required.